# Elasticsearch restore data in case of machine (node) failure

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose

I have got a single machine in which I have set up 3 nodes elastic using docker-compose.
Here is my docker-compose file

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.3.2
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms24g -Xmx24g"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 5051:9200
    networks:
      - esnet
  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.3.2
    container_name: es02
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms24g -Xmx24g"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet
  es03:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.3.2
    container_name: es03
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms24g -Xmx24g"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.3.2
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: kibana.local
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://es01:9200
    ports:
      - '5601:5601'
    networks:
      - esnet

volumes:
  esdata01:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/ebs/esdata01'
  esdata02:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/ebs/esdata02'
  esdata03:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/ebs/esdata03'

networks:
  esnet:
```

The mount location is an  external location

> /ebs/esdata01

**The problem is the machine has been crashed now.**

What I want to ask is if I get a **new machine** and set up the **same docker-compose** there, whether I will be able to see the existing data in corresponding indexes? 
If not, then what is the alternative way to do so?

Comment: each node needs to be able to talk to each other, which requires some docker-compose network configuration, and every node needs to have access to that external file system location. they need to have the same es cluster name, and you probably need some shard rebalancing after you can see the data, and set replicas to at least 2.

Comment: If the `/ebs` directory is an AWS EBS volume, and you remount the same volume on a new EC2 instance, then this will probably work.  Is there a specific problem you're encountering?  (Note that this isn't an especially effective "multi-node" Elasticsearch setup for exactly the reason you've run into, and also that the "nodes" will contend with each other for CPU, memory, and disk I/O.)

Comment: @David I wasn't sure whether it will work so to avoid any problems I wanted to be sure.. Yes /ebs is a shared volume which we remounted on another machine. As per your suggestion I tried and fortunately it worked